# Apache Phoenix date field query in Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

We have an table being populated by Apache Phoenix.  The table has a column that is a Date and is being populated as such.

We would like to be able to retrieve the data using the standard HBase java client.

```
byte[] valueBytes = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes(columnName));
```

We have tried to parse it to Long, String, etc...but the data is just not correct.

Any advise on how to get the data would be appreciated.

:)